# How to initialise multiple array in single line in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, initialization, array-initialization

I'm trying to do some calculations and get the groups and departments array from there.
but if I'm returning it like this [], [] It is giving error, while if I return it like [[],[]]
it is working fine but in the later case, 3 arrays will get initialize which I want to avoid?
Is there any better way to do it using 2 array itself?

```
    def fetch_group_dept_values
      if condition
        [1,2,3,], [4,5]
      else  
        [9,15], [10,11]
      end
    end

    groups, departments = fetch_group_dept_values
```

Comment: In the case you must return Array of Arrays.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that as it will initialize 3 arrays instead of 2?

Comment: The issue is resolved, if I use return in front then it is possible to do so, my mentor @Amala_Ray have suggested it.

Comment: According to the Ruby Language Specification, return multiple values *is done by allocation an array*, so there is no difference *semantically*. Pragmatically, there is also no difference, because an optimizing compiler like TruffleRuby will optimize the array away in both cases. So, *semantically*, there will *always* be 3 arrays, whereas *pragmatically*, depending on your Ruby implementation, there will always be 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I return it like `[[],[]]` it is working fine but in the later case, 3 arrays will get initialize which I want to avoid?

It cannot be avoided because a method can only return a *single* object.

So wrapping the objects in `[...]` is just fine:

```
def fetch_group_dept_values
  if condition
    [[1, 2, 3,], [4, 5]]
  else  
    [[9, 15], [10, 11]]
  end
end
```

The overhead of creating a (small) extra array is negligible.

However, you could avoid the outer array by *yielding* the values instead of returning them:

```
def fetch_group_dept_values
  if condition
    yield [1, 2, 3,], [4, 5]
  else  
    yield [9, 15], [10, 11]
  end
end
```

And call it via:

```
fetch_group_dept_values do |groups, departments|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: But you *can* write an explicit `return` with a list of multiple values, which is however *exactly the same* as returning an `Array`. E.g. `def foo; return 1, 2, 3, end` is exactly the same as `def foo; [1, 2, 3] end`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `yield a, b, c` is _not_ the same as `yield [a, b, c]` – see the example for [`next_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next_values).

Comment: Oh, whow, I never noticed this asymmetry. Indeed, `return`, `break`, and `next` all work the same (In the ISO Ruby Language Specification, `break` and `next` *literally* just refer to `return`) but `yield` works different. Well, well, well, one never ceases to learn.

Comment: I would like to add that yielding is most likely not worth the hassle. Creating an array with two references to two other arrays doesn't take up much resources. Such an optimisation can be made. If OP is worried about system resources I'm sure OP can find better things to optimize in their program.

Comment: An alternative to `yield` is to return an enumerator that generates arrays (e.g., `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5]`).

Answer (score 1):

Use return in front,

```
   def fetch_group_dept_values
      if condition
        return [1,2,3,], [4,5]
      else  
        return [9,15], [10,11]
      end
    end

    groups, departments = fetch_group_dept_values
```

Comment: Note that this wraps the return values in an array *anyway*, because `return a, b` is defined to be the same as `return [a, b]`. A Sufficiently Smart Compiler™ *may* optimize the array away for cases like `def foo; return 1, 2 end; a, b = foo`, but then it will also optimize away `def foo; [1, 2] end; a, b = foo` in the same way, so there is no difference.